# Issue in deploying website with .srf files on IIS

Tags: windows, iis, module, isapi

I am facing an issue in deploying website with .srf files on IIS. Getting an isapi module error. Installed asp.net, extensibility, CGI and ISAPI restrictions as required.

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, so it cannot be displayed.
Most likely causes:
•   The path to the ISAPI Filter is incorrect.
•   IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
•   IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
•   IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
•   The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.

Detailed Error Information:
Module:                               IsapiModule
Notification:                       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler :                              TestRemote
Error Code:                         0x8007007e
Requested URL:                http://localhost:80/TestRemote/Banner.srf
Physical Path                      D:\wwwroot\Test\TestRemote\Banner.srf
Logon Method                  Anonymous
Logon User                         Anonymous
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description and error message, it seems there are something wrong about creating mapping for the .srf file.

I suggest you could try to follow below steps to re-add the mapping for mapping between files with the .srf and .dll extensions and the new ISAPI extension DLL.

Steps as below:

1.Generate an ATL Server ISAPI extension DLL using the [ATL Server Project Wizard.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/ebdeawat(v=vs.100))

2.Build the ISAPI extension DLL and copy it to your Web server.

3.Create a mapping between files with the .srf and .dll extensions and the new ISAPI extension DLL.

For example:

(1)Run Internet Services Manager.

(2)Right-click the appropriate Web site or virtual directory in the tree and click Properties on the shortcut menu.

(3)Click the Home Directory or Virtual Directory property page.

(4)Click the Configuration button.

(5)Click the App Mappings property page.

(6)Click Add.

(7)Enter the path to your ISAPI DLL in the Executable text box.

(8)Enter .srf in the Extension text box.

(9)Click OK.

(10)Click Add.

(11)Enter the path to your ISAPI DLL in the Executable text box.

(12)Click .dll in the Extension text box.

(13)Click OK until all dialog boxes are accepted.